# Implementing Barabasi-Albert Method for Creating Scale-Free Networks

Tags: implementation, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a very simple preferential attachment algorithm for creating scale-free networks. These have degree distributions that follow a power-law, i.e. P(k) ~ k^-g, where g is the exponent. The algorithm below should produce degree distributions with the exponent equal 3 +/- 0.1, my implementation does not the exponents are closer to 2.5 +/- 0.1. I'm clearly not understanding something somewhere and continue to get it wrong.

I'm sorry if this is in the wrong place, I couldn't decide whether it should be in stackoverflow or maths.stackexchange.com.

```
The Algorithm:
Input: Number of Nodes N; Minimum degree d >= 1.
Output: scale-free multigraph
G = ({0,....,N-1}, E)
M: array of length 2Nd
for (v=0,...,n-1)
   for (i=0,...,d-1)
      M[2(vd+i)] = v;
      r = random number selected uniformly at random from {0,.....,2(vd+i)};
      M[2(vd+i)+1] = M[r];
   end
end

E = {};
for (i=0,...,nd-1)
   E[i] = {M[2i], M[2i+1]}
end
```

My Implementation in C/C++:

```
void SF_LCD(std::vector< std::vector<int> >& graph, int N, int d) {
    if(d < 1 || d > N - 1) {
        std::cerr << "Error: SF_LCD: k_min is out of bounds: " << d;
    }

    std::vector<int> M;
    M.resize(2 * N * d);

    int r = -1;
    //Use Batagelj's implementation of the LCD model
    for(int v = 0; v < N; v++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            M[2 * (v * d + i)] = v;
             r = mtr.randInt(2 * (v * d + i));
            M[2 * (v * d + i) + 1] = M[r];
        }
    }

    //create the adjacency list
    graph.resize(N);
    bool exists = false;
    for(int v = 0; v < M.size(); v += 2) {
        int m = M[v];
        int n = M[v + 1];

        graph[m].push_back(n);
        graph[n].push_back(m);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a degree distribution I get for N = 10,000 and d = 1:

```
1   6674
2   1657
3   623
4   350
5   199
6   131
7   79
8   53
9   57
10  27
11  17
12  20
13  15
14  12
15  5
16  8
17  5
18  10
19  7
20  6
21  5
22  6
23  4
25  4
26  2
27  1
28  6
30  2
31  1
33  1
36  2
37  2
43  1
47  1
56  1
60  1
63  1
64  1
67  1
70  1
273 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so I couldn't figure out how to make this particular algorithm work correctly, instead I used another one.

```
The Algorithm:
Input: Number of Nodes N; 
       Initial number of nodes m0; 
       Offset Exponent a; 
       Minimum degree 1 <= d <= m0.
Output: scale-free multigraph G = ({0,....,N-1}, E).

1) Add m0 nodes to G.
2) Connect every node in G to every other node in G, i.e. create a complete graph.
3) Create a new node i.
4) Pick a node j uniformly at random from the graph G. Set P = (k(j)/k_tot)^a.
5) Pick a real number R uniformly at random between 0 and 1.
6) If P > R then add j to i's adjacency list.
7) Repeat steps 4 - 6 until i has m nodes in its adjacency list.
8) Add i to the adjacency list of each node in its adjacency list.
9) Add i to to the graph.
10) Repeat steps 3 - 9 until there are N nodes in the graph.
```

Where k(j) is the degree of node j in the graph G and k_tot is twice the number of edges (the total number of degrees) in the graph G.

By altering the parameter a one can control the exponent of the degree distribution. a = 1.22 gives me an exponent g (in P(k) ~ k^-g) of 3 +/- 0.1.

Comment: A comment from @RobertWhite: "I think there is a small mistake in the algorithm. The original nodes should not be connected. I asked my lecturer and she confirmed. Sorry that my post was too simple. Hope it is clear now."

Comment: @yan-sklyarenko The initial nodes must have some connections. A node that has degree 0 initially will remain that way because the probability of connecting with it will always be 0. Similarly, if the initial network has no edges, the resulting network will also have no edges.