# Is my subroutine correct for generating a random Barabasi-Albert graph?

Tags: algorithm, random, fortran, social-networking, graph-algorithm

I would like to generate a random Barabasi-Albert graph with 10,000 node, but my program is very slow. Can anybody help if my subroutine is correct or not? In my code ran1() is the standard random number generator. Thanks for the help.

```
 ***********************************************************************
      subroutine barabasi_albert(kon,n,m0,m,a,idum)
 ***********************************************************************
      implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
      implicit integer*4(i-n)
      logical linked(n)    ! logical array for storing if a node is connected 
                           ! to the current one
      dimension kon(n,n)   ! connectivity matrix 
                           ! m0: number of initial nodes
                           ! m: minimal degree
                           ! a: scale parameter
                           ! idum: argument to the random number generation
c
c Initialize kon(:,:)
c                           
      kon(:n,:n)=0
c
c Create complete graph of m0 node 
c                          
      kon(:m0,:m0)=1
      do i=1,m0
         kon(i,i)=0
      end do
c
c Extend the graph with n-m0 node
c      
      do i=m0+1,n
         linked(:i)=.false.
c
c Add edges while the vertex degree of the ith node is less than m
c         
         do
            if(sum(kon(i,:i-1)).eq.m) exit
            ii=floor(dble(i-1)*ran1(idum))+1
            if(.not.linked(ii)) then
               p=(dble(sum(kon(ii,:i-1)))/sum(kon(:i-1,:i-1)))**a
               if(p.gt.ran1(idum)) then
                  kon(i,ii)=1
                  kon(ii,i)=1
                  linked(ii)=.true.
               endif
            endif
         end do
      end do
      end
```

Some links connected to:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454188/why-does-my-barabasi-albert-model-implementation-doesnt-produce-a-scale-free-ne

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824097/creating-barab%c3%a1si-albertba-graph-with-spacific-node-and-edgs

[Implementing Barabasi-Albert Method for Creating Scale-Free Networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622401/implementing-barabasi-albert-method-for-creating-scale-free-networks)

Comment: Are you familiar with time complexity?

Comment: Btw I'm interpreting your question as "how can I speed up my program" rather than "does it do the correct thing".

Comment: I believe this is better suited for code-review. And there is actually already code for this posted there: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/131894/38801

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Fortran, but a few things stand out. First consider the time complexity of your function. You have two nested loops. The first one runs `n` times, where `n` is proportional to the size of the input. The second runs until it has found `m0` connections. But inside the innermost loop you calculate the sums of parts of the array. First sum consists of `i*(i-1)` additions, that's probably the most costly. So the time complexity is limited by `O(n*m0*i^2)`. Assuming `m0` is small, this becomes `O(n^3)`.

The best improvement I think is to change to an algorithm with lower time complexity, but if that's not possible you can still tweak what you have. First, cache your sums. Don't calculate the same sum twice. Or if you calculate `sum(1:i)`, save that result and use when you calculate `sum(1:i+1)` or `sum(1:i-1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Apart from the summation, do you think my subroutine correct? Does it reflect the algorithm? I will try to improve time complexity.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read Fortran well enough to say. I suggest you try it with a small graph a couple of times and manually check if the answer is a correct graph. 5-10 elements should be enough.

Comment: I have fitted the vertex-degree distribution with the function f(v)=v^(-g) (v: vertex degree, f(v): relative frequency of v, g: constant). I have obtained g=1.91+-0.1 instead of g ~ 3. Is it to be said good or not?

Comment: I don't know, not familiar with Barabasi-Albert graphs. It should mean fewer connections between nodes.